# How to create a line in Shapely using starting point, length, and an angle

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

I found this code but it requires both first and second point to create a line. How can I change it so it works with only first point, length of the line, and an angle?

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point

p = Point(5,5)
c = p.buffer(3).boundary
l = LineString([(0,0), (10, 10)])
i = c.intersection(l)

print i.geoms[0].coords[0]
(2.8786796564403576, 2.8786796564403576)

print i.geoms[1].coords[0]
(7.121320343559642, 7.121320343559642)
```

Comment: Shapely doesn't support infinite lines. If you want to construct a LineString of finite length, just a point and an angle is not enough. We need also information about the length of the LineString, or the x or y coordinate of the second point.

Comment: Calculate the second point at distance `L` with angle `Fi`: `x2 = x1 + L * cos(Fi)  y2 = y1 + L * sin(Fi)`

Comment: @Georgy i have length too, could you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 8):

You have several options:

1. Calculate the coordinates of the second point using basic trigonometry:

   ```
   import math
   from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

   start = Point(0, 0)
   length = 1
   angle = math.pi / 3

   end = Point(start.x + length * math.cos(angle),
               start.y + length * math.sin(angle))
   line = LineString([start, end])
   print(line)
   # LINESTRING (0 0, 0.5000000000000001 0.8660254037844386)
   ```

   If your angle is not in radians but in degrees, you should convert it first:

   ```
   angle = 60
   angle = math.radians(angle)
   ```

2. Make a horizontal line with the given start point and length, and then [`rotate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.affinity.rotate) it by given angle around the first point:

   ```
   from shapely.affinity import rotate
   from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

   start = Point(0, 0)
   length = 1
   angle = math.pi / 3

   end = Point(start.x + length, start.y)
   line = LineString([start, end])
   line = rotate(line, angle, origin=start, use_radians=True)
   print(line)
   # LINESTRING (0 0, 0.5000000000000001 0.8660254037844386)
   ```

   Note that by default `rotate` function expects angles in degrees, so if we want to pass an angle in radians to it, we have to use the `use_radians=True` as shown above.

   Alternatively, we could also use [`translate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.affinity.translate) function to get the endpoint:

   ```
   from shapely.affinity import translate
   end = translate(start, length)
   ```